# Cast to ObjectId failed for value "some_id" at path "_id" for model "Category"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

when I use findOne from mongoose version 5.9.12, I got some error like this :
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7SrP.png)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kAcY.png

my code:
[code][2]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8Prd.png

my models:
[models](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7SrP.png)

Comment: Please edit your question and add your `code` instead of posting images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the mongoose [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById):

> If you want to query by a document's _id, use findById() instead of
> findOne().
>
> The id is cast based on the Schema before sending the command.

So the recommended way to do this is:

```
Category.findById(categoryId)
```

---

If you really want to use `findOne` and specify `_id` inside the filter, you can convert the string using

```
Category.findOne( { _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(categoryId) })
```

to an `ObjectId`.

---

Edit: The actual problem is that your `categoryId` contains a trailing whitespace which causes this problem: `"5f05445a9789663d08fb12d2 "` - it should be `"5f05445a9789663d08fb12d2"`.

Comment: when i use ur code, i got some error again. the error say : 'Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters'

Comment: what should do i?

Comment: Even when using `Category.findById(categoryId)` ?

Comment: Ahh wait - you have a trailing whitespace in your `categoryId` - you need to remove this. `"5f05445a9789663d08fb12d2 "` should be `"5f05445a9789663d08fb12d2"`

Comment: @Farhurrahman: please accept the answer, if it was helpful. Thank you :)